# How to set default Volume?

Tags: android, checkbox, volume

My checkbox have to mute musicbackroud. How to change back to the default volume?

```
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            musicbackground.setVolume(0, 0);}
            else
            {
                ???
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As far as I can tell](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp?h=aosp-new/master#n43) the initial volume for a `MediaPlayer` is `1.0`.

So you could keep track of the current and previous volume with a couple of extra variables:

```
float currentVolume = 1.0f;
float previousVolume = 1.0f;

...

// Changing volume to 0
previousVolume = currentVolume;
currentVolume = 0;
musicbackground.setVolume(currentVolume, currentVolume);

...

// Restoring the old volume
temp = previousVolume;
previousVolume = currentVolume;
currentVolume = temp;
musicbackground.setVolume(currentVolume, currentVolume);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on musicbackground.setVolume(1, 1). I don't know that ;p